# Failed to install package BeautifulSoup in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Failed to install package BeautifulSoup in pycharm,
it shows Error occurred when installing package BeautifulSoup,
i am using python 3.6.5,

Below i am writting the process ,how i try to install it
Open pycharm,then go to setting ,python interpreter ,then there on available packages install BeautifulSoup.

By clicking on installPackage it shows Error Occurred when installing Package "BeautifulSoup".

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show the command you issued to install it and the *full error log*. As your question stands there is not enough information to tell what the error was. Without that, it's hard to tell you how  to fix the problem. Please [edit] your question to provide the log, as text. Don't try put it in a comment and don't post a picture.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the file from here:https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2/#modal-close
and move the file to where you want to install, then open the cmd and move to the directory the BeautifulSoup is and run the code:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```